# How to do CSRF verification along with Bearer token in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, csrf, laravel-passport, bearer-token

Pardon me If I am wrong.

I am going to build a system by using Angular and Laravel API and these are some things about what I am doing.

- I am using Passport and I am successfully able to do authentication.
- I also want to do a CSRF verification because still I don't know where to store the token. If I store on cookies its vulnerable for CSRF (Thats why need to do a CSRF). What if I store bearer token on local storage ? Should I need to do a CSRF verfify ?.
- How can I do a CSRF verify along with bearer token? (using web middleware)

Comment: I have done something. I will tell here but still I don't have that much idea.

I am using a middleware " \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class," for accessing session on my api and I am using another middleware for generate csrf  on every GET request and respond with a "csrf" header. I collect the csrf and request for a POST endpoint by using it on header. CSRF will be verified on a middleware and on success respond with data.

In this way I can send bearer token on cookie and csrf on header. Is this approach is correct ?

Comment: Yes its the correct approach and one more thing. I am modifying the request header on index.php like this,

if(isset($_COOKIE['token'])){
    $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Bearer '.$_COOKIE['token'];
}

So passport will do its authentication on its own way

Comment: Finally CLOSED.

Comment: Are you using Laravel `DB` session storage? If not, then how would you verify the `CSRF` token sent to the `server`?

Comment: I am using \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, so it will be stored on session and besides of csrf response header i am also setting a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN. (for angular)

Comment: How does `StartSession` works with `stateless` application?

Comment: if we can set cookies then whats the difference there. We can load whatever the middleware we want. So I used session middleware so then the laravel_session cookie will be there

Comment: If i want to store token on local storage, then there is no need of all these. If need the token should be in cookie, then i have too